# Mobile internet (3G) in UK for some days

Tags: internet, wifi, cambridge

At the end of June I will be headed to Cambridge (UK) for a conference. The conference lasts three days. However, I'll stay there for four days.

Is it possible to have a mobile (and preferably cheap!) Internet connection?

I know that for instance in Finland you can buy a SIM card for 10€, and this gives you 7 days of (I guess limited) connection.

Is there the same possibility up there in Cambridge?

In case there is not any of these possibilities, are there at least restaurants/cafes which offer you free WiFi?

My hotel, unfortunately, doesn't.

Comment: There's at least half a dozen options available! Did you try looking at some of the other questions we've already got on the site?

Comment: Yes, obviously I did, but I did not find anything about the UK and the limited specified time.

Comment: Did the [answers in this question on pre-paid data for the UK](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18644/26) not cover you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Three](http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/phones-broadband-gps/mobile-phones-and-broadband/pay-as-you-go-mobile-broadband/three-mobile-broadband-1-gb-preloaded-pay-as-you-go-sim-card-13828907-pdt.html?awc=1599_1401736724_6b4cc357fb31fc2cb7e5b832e361cd0f&srcid=369&xtor=AL-1&cmpid=aff~HotUKDeals~Communities%20&%20UGC&istCompanyId=bec25c7e-cbcd-460d-81d5-a25372d2e3d7&istItemId=qqpxmxaq&istBid=t) is offering a SIM for mobile use only with a 1GB allowance for a measly £2.99. In order to buy it, either ask someone residing in the UK to get it for you or select collect in store and choose a store close to the conference location. Hope this helps.

Comment: This would be super great. However, I was thinking about obtaining a nanoSIM (I have an iPhone and a SIM is not suitable). On the website I cannot find this info. Do you have further info on this?

Comment: Here! http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/phones-broadband-gps/mobile-phones-and-broadband/pay-as-you-go-mobile-broadband/three-mobile-broadband-1-gb-preloaded-pay-as-you-go-nano-sim-for-ipad-air-ipad-mini-retina-19597894-pdt.html?sPageInfo=1_20&sSortInfo=price-asc

Comment: There you go, you found it :) Well spotted!

Answer (score 2):

There are various pay-as-you-go providers, I personally use [GiffGaff](http://giffgaff.com/gigabags). I also used [LycaMobile](http://www.lycamobile.co.uk/en/bundles?id=4) before. They both offer monthly bundles with data (or minutes+texts+data if you prefer this option). You can buy a bundle for just one month, so this would be your cost.